# Add a Framework to a Project in .Net Core3 in VS 2019

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I have created a project in VS 2019 using the "Class Library (.NET Core)" template.  Now I need to add the "Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App" framework to the Dependencies\Frameworks "folder".

Anyone know how to do this without recreating the project from scratch?

Comment: Change the first line of your project file to `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">` and then toggle `UseWindowsForms` or `UseWPF`.

Comment: OMG.  That's just crazy.  Thanks.